# Error when calling Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Normally i don't work with Oracle DB, but today i had to write a small stored procedure that returns a GUID. (Data Type RAW according to Oracle)

This is what i have created. I can compile the stored procedure, but when i execute it, i get the following error: **String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767).**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetId (MyInputVar IN VARCHAR2, Guid OUT RAW)
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT "unid" into Guid FROM MyDB."incident" WHERE "ExternalId" = GetId.MyInputVar;
END;


DECLARE GiveMeTheGuid RAW;
        OtherSystemOrderId VARCHAR2 (60 CHAR) := 'ORDERNR1000';
BEGIN 
  Sitefinity_Order_NR(OtherSystemOrderId, GiveMeTheGuid);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(GiveMeTheGuid);
END;
```

Comment: The error also gives you a line number and procedure name; as you haven't included all the code it would be helpful to include the full error.

Comment: you need to issue this command before executing your procedure SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAW variable declaration needs a size.

```
DECLARE
  theID RAW(32);
  OtherSystemOrderId VARCHAR2 (60 CHAR) := 'ORDERNR1000';
BEGIN
  GetID(OtherSystemOrderId, theID);
  dbms_output.put_line('unid is ' || theID);
END;
```

anonymous block completed

unid is 3F66DF77FC234C7B887A18F33C174A6A

Comment: I think you could just summarize this as "GiveMeTheGuid RAW; should be GiveMeTheGuid RAW(32);".